# Error in grDevices::png

Tags: r

```
quick.hist<-ggplot(ufo.us, aes(X=DateOccured))+geom_histogram()+scale_x_date()
ggsave(plot=quick.hist,filename= "../images/hist.png",height=6, width=8)
```

file format is simple:

it contains 2 dates,city,state,duration

I am getting error during plot:that is during `ggsave()`

```
Error in grDevices::png(..., width = width, height = height, res = dpi,  
  unable to start png() device
```

In addition: Warning messages:

```
 In grDevices::png(..., width = width, height = height, res = dpi,  
  unable to open file '../images/hist.png' for writing

 In grDevices::png(..., width = width, height = height, res = dpi,  
  opening device failed
```

I am very new to R and getting error. I have just started copying the book code for histogram chart, first chapter from book machine learning hacker perspective.

Comment: try another file format, e.g. pdf, and a simpler file path e.g. "hist.pdf"

Comment: Have you got the file open in another program?

Comment: @baptiste - this is almost certainly a directory permissions (or nonexistent directory) problem, not png vs pdf.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft I'm having the same issue. And it seems to be **png vs pdf**. Pdf save works ok

Comment: @Ilya if you can repeat the issue, it's probably worth sending your example, along with your operating system,  R-version, etc. to the maintainer of `grDevices`

Comment: @Carl Witthoft I will. In a [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270349/ggsave-png-error-with-larger-size) I found how to get around the problem. The devil is in `dpi` parameter of `ggsave`. The default is 300. Empirically I chose 192, as 256 produced the similar error.

Comment: check if 'images' folder exists

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem recently. It occurs when compiling R from source without having the appropriate libraries installed. So R does not know how to talk to the png device at all.

In order to fix this problem just install the following packages (e.g. using Ubuntu16.04)

```
sudo apt install libcairo2-dev libjpeg9-dev
```

and run the ./configure again.

If those libraries were sufficient both **PNG** and **cairo** should be listed as *Additional capabilities* at the end of the configuration. So if none of them shows up using

```
cat config.log | grep skipped
```

you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. In my case, my working directory (check `getwd`) was not the right one so the `filepath` didn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem as the OP.  It appeared to be an error from `ggsave()` but I traced it back to a `ggarrange()` call.  I was hitting my limit of open devices (~64) and needed to call `dev.off()` following each `ggarrange()` call.  This post was helpful: [Too many open devices r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207960/too-many-open-devices-r)